# Fetching data from API for ReasonReact app

Tags: fetch, reason, reason-react

I'm learning ReasonReact and I would like to fetch data from a API, that I'm going to use on my component. However, on the official website about Reason or ReasonReact there's nothing about this, neither I found something searching on Google. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the existing bindings to HTTP client libraries, e.g.:

- https://redex.github.io/package/bs-fetch
- https://redex.github.io/package/bs-axios

The former works in browser only, the latter works in both browser and Node.

In general, if you're looking for a way to do something, Redex is a great place to look.

Comment: Well, didn't know about Redex! Thanks for this! About bs-fetch, I did see it when searching on Google, I just though there could be a "native" way of doing this. Seems that bs-fetch is the way for me!

Comment: `bs-fetch` works in node too, just not out-of-the-box. It requires a polyfill: <https://github.com/reasonml-community/bs-fetch#nodejs-polyfill>